# GET request resets member value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, get-request

Attempting to build a simple api, but ran into a problem where a member is seemingly reset to the default value after a GET request. Funny thing is; the first time I send a request, the expected result is returned, any subsequent requests however seem to result in some data loss. Why does this happen? Why does it not happen for the first request? How do I fix it?

(I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2)

```
namespace RestaurantReviewApi.Controllers {
    [Route("api/restaurants")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RestaurantsController : ControllerBase {
        private readonly RestaurantContext _context;

        public RestaurantsController(RestaurantContext context) {
            _context = context;

            // Create a new Restaurant if collection is empty
            if(_context.Restaurants.Count() == 0) {
                Restaurant firstRestaurant = new Restaurant {
                    Reviews = new List<Review> {
                        new Review { }
                    }
                };

                _context.Restaurants.Add(firstRestaurant);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        // GET: api/restaurants
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Restaurant>>> GetRestaurants() {
            return await _context.Restaurants.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace RestaurantReviewApi.Models {
    public class Restaurant {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
        public double AverageRating { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace RestaurantReviewApi.Models {
    public class Review {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Stars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace RestaurantReviewApi.Models {
    public class RestaurantContext : DbContext {
        public RestaurantContext(DbContextOptions<RestaurantContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    }
}
```

First request (https://localhost:port/api/restaurants) gives me this output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": null,
        "address": null,
        "reviews": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "author": null,
                "text": null,
                "stars": 0
            }
        ],
        "averageRating": 0.0
    }
]
```

Subsequent identical requests give this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": null,
        "address": null,
        "reviews": null,
        "averageRating": 0.0
    }
]
```

SOLUTION:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Restaurant>>> GetRestaurants()
{
     return await _context.Restaurants.Include(r => r.Reviews).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: I suspect the review isn't being written to the database, and the first request is simply returning the object that the dbcontext has cached.  Subsequent requests won't have the same dbcontext, so the cached object doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Before we proceed, can you take a moment and confirm that it isn't being written to the database?

Comment: Hey! Ty for the quick reply! Any idea how to make sure the object gets written to the db?

Comment: Use SSMS or some other database tool to look at the database table?

Comment: Here's the thing.  There are two possibilities here: (1) it isn't being written, so there's nothing wrong with the second request; or, (2) it is being written, so there *is* something wrong with the second request.  We need to know which it is before we can proceed.

Comment: I'm guessing it just isn't being written, since the second request is identical. I'm running out of time for today though. Will come back to this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first request , the result of `_context.Restaurants` is the value of your constructor initialization in the controller when `_context.Restaurants.Count() == 0`  , not query from the database .

For Subsequent identical requests , you query the Restaurants from the database . If you want to query related data ,you should use the `Include` method to specify related data to be included in query results .

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Restaurant>>> GetRestaurants()
{
     return _context.Restaurants.Include(r=>r.Reviews).ToList();
}
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common mistake. Even after working with C# and Entity Framework for years, I find myself doing this at times as well. Make sure that your `Reviews` property is virtual.

```
public class Restaurant {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public double AverageRating { get; set; }
}
```

This is because when Entity Framework does the query, you don't actually get a `Restaurant` object back: it's a dynamic proxy class that's autogenerated. Thus, EF has to replace your `List<Review>` with a `List<System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Review_AF34E90301>` (long hex string at the end). Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/proxies for details.

Comment: Sadly, this did not change the result. Thanks for the tip though, will remember this if I run into a similar problem later.